# Passing value of dynamically filled dropdownlist to PHP file

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I need to pass the option value to `php/lend.php` to make a query with that value. I tried to post the value and `echo` them in the `lend.php` file but it says `'undefined index'`. Can someone please look through my code to see if I'm doing something wrong?

**Dropdownlist file**:

```
<form action="php/lend.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="input-group">
        <select id="selectapparaat" name="selectapparaat" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" onchange="grabDevice(this.value)">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Naam apparaat</option>
            <?php
                $queryapparaten = "SELECT apparaatnaam FROM apparaten ";
                $db = mysqli_query($db,$queryapparaten);
                while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
                    echo "<option value='".$d['apparaatnaam']."'>".$d['apparaatnaam']."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" disabled type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="uitlenen" style="width: 100%;">Uitlenen</button>
</form>
```

**php/lend.php:**

```
<?php
    require 'database.php';

    if (isset($_POST['uitlenen'])) {
       $a = $_POST['apparaatnaam'];
       $b = $_POST['clientnaam'];
       $c = $_POST['organisatienaam'];

       echo $a;
       echo "</br>";
       echo $b;
       echo "</br>";
       echo $c;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form is no input named apparaatnaam, clientnaam and organisatienaam. Therefore those 3 post variables you want to read will not be defined.

What you do have in your form is selectapparaat, so you could read the selected option with `$_POST['selectapparaat']`

> edit: I can also recommend using the apparaatid for the value of the
>   options, not their names. (Only if you use the selected value for
>   further DB-querys.) This will make the further queries easier and does
>   not require apparaatnaam to be unique.

```
$queryapparaten = "SELECT id, apparaatnaam FROM apparaten ";
$db = mysqli_query($db,$queryapparaten);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo "<option value='".$d['id']."'>".$d['apparaatnaam']."</option>";
}
```

> edit2: oh and one more thing, it seems you are overwriting your
>   db-connection-variable with the result of the query. further db
>   queries on this page will therefore not work. try this instead

```
$queryapparaten = "SELECT id, apparaatnaam FROM apparaten ";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$queryapparaten);
while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips, this is very usefull for me ;)